# Visual Studio 2008 Publish Feature in a desktop app. What are the benefits?

Tags: visual-studio, publishing

Today I tried to use the publishing feature with visual studio, which creates an application manifest, and not a traditional exe.

What are the benefits of this?

I noticed each time the app starts up it does some kind of check before launching in?

Comment: I removed "asp.net" from your tags, since your question is about desktop applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using *Publish* on a Windows application, you create a *ClickOnce* installer. You can find a lot of information about that in the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx). Basically, this is an alternative to creating a conventional MSI-based setup project (`File/New/Project/Other Project Types/Setup and Deployment/Setup Project`).

On MSDN you can find a [comparison of the two approaches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2444w33.aspx).